# how to use xpath for the following case

Tags: selenium, webdriver, xpath

```
.//*[@id='colDiv_Apr282014']/div[5]/div[1]
.//*[@id='colDiv_Apr282014']/div[9]/div[1]
.//*[@id='colDiv_Apr282014']/div[11]/div[1]
```

In the xpath above, you can see the value inside the first div-is getting changed everytime. ts not constant. I want to use a comman xpath format for the above case so that I can execute the test cases 20 times. How can this be done?

Following is the screenshot of how the page looks.

[image]

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing the structure of the document.

Comment: (dropmocks.com/mETuQJ). **It is a calendar page, clicking on the horizontal lines, popup will openup allowing to book appointments. I want to locate the timeslots exactly.**
`<div class="cal-event new-cal-event ui-corner-all ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="line-height: 18px; font-size: 10px; top: 80px; height: 40px; display: block;">
<div class="time ui-corner-all">01:00 am to 01:30 am</div>
<div class="title">New Event</div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
</div>
</div>
</td>`
**This is how the timeslots are created in the page**

Comment: Does the `<div>` that you want to access have any unique attribute? ID, class, value, etc?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I cannot comment yet, so please no downvotes. :-)

There were few views of this question, no answers, and unlikely any answer is coming. See:

- [Best Practices for Selenium locators](http://mestachs.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/selenium-best-practices/) prefers to use ID, Name or CSS over XPATH.
- This [locator comparison](https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators.html) says XPATH is slower and brittle, especially in IE.

So non-answer is: "don't do that" :-)

Can you change page/ask it to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElements(.//*[@id='colDiv_Apr282014']/div)`. It has to be findElements with 's' on end. That way You will get list of element. When filter obtained result if some not meet expected criteria.

Comment: @SkorpEN- Uniquely identifying the element somehow will be much easier. Using a list will complicate things, IMO, as he will have to uniquely identify the element in the list too.

Comment: But if elements id is changeing this is the simplest solution I know. Of course You could ask programmers for unique id or name, still if You can not change locators it is simple enough solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
.//*[@id='colDiv_Apr282014']//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' time ')]
```